# SslStream To Byte Array

Tags: c#, arrays, networking, memory, stream

I'm just learning C# and trying to update the legacy code. I need to convert SslStream (old code, main.cs) to byte array (new code, utils.cs).

```
while (true)
{
  // Get the RPC Header (main.cs)
  Header rpcHeader = Header.ParseFrom(stream);
}

public static T ParseFrom<T>(byte[] bytes, int offset = 0, int length = -1) where T : IProtoBuf, new()
{
  // ParseBytes (utils.cs)
  if (length == -1)
  {
    length = bytes.Length;
  }
  MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes, offset, length);
  T result = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
  result.Deserialize(stream);
  return result;
}
```

Is this possible in principle, is it not a stupid idea?

I apologize if the question looks like "do everything for me", I will be glad if at least tell me the direction of thinking.

Thank you all, good luck!

Sorry, I forgot about the intermediary function, here it is:

```
public static Header ParseFrom(byte[] bs)
{
  return ProtobufUtil.ParseFrom<Header>(bs, 0, -1);
}
```

Comment: I'm confused, what's wrong with the above code? Although it's hard to work out where [tag:networking] and `SslStream` comes into this

Comment: I admit that due to ignorance of the language I can ask confusing questions (My Sorry). My variable stream of type SslStream does not want to get into the ParseFrom function, since it cannot be converted to byte[]. Is it possible to convert SslStream to byte array so that the function starts accepting it?

Comment: Why do you need to do that? Just change the function to accept a `Stream` directly, and then pass it `result.Deserialize`

Comment: I don’t understand much about this, maybe this is some kind of stupid decision, thanks for the hint, sorry again 

Comment: So basically you want `public static T ParseFrom<T>(Stream stream) where T : IProtoBuf, new()`

Comment: You saved me and my little understanding of C#! Thanks, it works, the question really looked very stupid... Guru!